# rebuild project cannot delete arr

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, I cannot **rebuild project** to get arr with the latest code suddenly. 
But it shows as follows:

......
Note: `XXX/src/androidTest/java/com/tr/attest/agent/ApplicationTest.java` uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

`:attestation_agent_sdk:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE`
`:attestation_agent_sdk:compileDebugAndroidTestSources`

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

And **clean project** cannot delete `build/outputs/arr directory`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the generated arr is built from the old code...

Comment: delete the build folder inside app then rebuild the project ..